# Inserting data into a partitioned table using DML

Tags: google-bigquery

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#inserting_data_into_partitioned_tables):

> Inserting data into a partitioned table using DML is the same as inserting data into a non-partitioned table.

For the non-partitioned table `test1.cities_non_partitioned`, below INSERT worked.

```
INSERT `test1.cities_non_partitioned` (city)
VALUES('Barcelona'),
      ('New York'),
      ('London'),
      ('Paris')
```

However, for the partitioned table `test1.cities`, the same query failed with:

> Error: Cannot query over table 'test1.cities' without a filter that can be used for partition elimination

Any thought?

**UPDATE**:

- Same error message after adding the _PARTITIONTIME:

[image]

- The schema of the partitioned table:
  [image]

Comment: Which partition are you trying to insert into? It doesn't look like you included the column in the list.

Comment: This is a bug in the compatibility of require_partition_filter with INSERT against partitioned tables. We will fix that bug shortly (we haven't fully documented require_partition_filter yet, but hopefully should be available soon)